# SUMO-Actuated tlLogic has no controlling detectors

Tags: veins, sumo

I'm new in SUMO, I generated the network scenario using osmWebWizard. but when I try to load the network in SUMO this Warning appears
"Warning: At actuated tlLogic 'cluster_453547327_60657211', linkIndex 3 has no controlling detector"
it appears so frequently at many junctions although it seems to be in their right locations but still issuing these warnings. I tried to join junctions to get rid of these warnings but nothing changed it still appear. Can anyone help me to eliminate these warnings please?
I'm using instant veins-5.2-i1

Comment: which SUMO version do you use?

Comment: I am using SUMO-1.11.0 within instant veins-5.2-i1